# Plotting a Fourier series using Matlab

Tags: fourier-series, matlab, signal-processing

i am trying to plot the following Fourier series $x(t)$

[image: x(t) CLICK TO VIEW]

```
t=0:0.01:2;
A = 10;
T = 2;
w0 = 2*pi/T;
N = 10;

xN = zeros(1,length(t)); % dc component
for n=1:N
   xN = xN + (1/(2*n-1)) * sin(2*n -1)*w0*t;
end

x = (4*A/pi) * xN;
plot(t,x)
xlabel('t')
ylabel('x(t)')
```

The result must be:

[image: this CLICK TO VIEW]

My code doesn't seem to be working, any help would be much appreciated,
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the symbolic toolbox - I find it nicer for doing things such as computing Fourier Series. Example code below.

```
syms t n k

A = 10;
w_0 = pi;

%% Formula for the Fourier Series

fourierseries = @(t,k) 4*A/pi*symsum(sin((2*n-1)*pi*t)/(2*n-1),n,1,k);

%% Plot with 20 Fourier coefficients

ezplot(fourierseries(t,20),-2,4)
title('Fourier Series'), xlabel('t'), ylabel('f(x)');
```

Comment: If this answer does answer your question then you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are wrong. Correct would be (note the added brackets after sin)

```
for n=1:N
  xN = xN + (1/(2*n-1)) * sin( (2*n -1)*w0*t );
end
```

The code the way you wrote it is interpreted differently. In your code the argument of the sine function is only (2*n-1), which is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function of the amplitude and frequency of the term inside the summation, depending only on `n` - the dummy variable.

Using the values you provided, you have:

```
A = 10;
T = 2;
w0 = 2*pi/T;
N = 10;
```

Now, the amplitude and frequency as function of the iterator `n` is:

```
a = @(n) 1./(2*n-1); % amplitude
w = @(n) (2*n-1)*w0; % frequency
```

Now, the (truncated) Fourier series may be give as:

```
xt = @(t,n) 4*A/pi*sum(a(1:n).*sin(w(1:n)*t)); % fourier series
```

This is a function of the number of terms `n` you want to include in your approximation of the infinite series and the also a number of the independent variable `t`.

If you want to create a plot of the function, you must create the independent variable array and the dependent variable array.

```
t = -2*T:T/100:T*2; % plots from -2T to 2T, with a step of T/100
x = 0*t; % pre-allocate for speed
for i=1:length(t)
    x(i) = xt(t(i),N); % calculates the value for each t(i) in the array t
end
figure
plot(t,x)
```

This code does not use any function from the symbolic toolbox that may not be available depending on your version of MATLAB.